# When testing on browserstack using intern, can i get intern's server to apply url-rewriting rules when running functional tests

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, intern

I'm writing an Angular js app and want to use html5mode.

I'm am using theintern.io to unit/ui test it.

This site shows what i need to do to configure my server to support this mode:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

The problem i am having is that i cannot find how to configure intern to do the same kind of thing. Intern is tunnelling from my Local machine to BStack to run the site.

I just get browserstack crashing because it cannot load the page it wants.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Intern server is not exposed in a way to enable this.  What you can do though it utilise a proxy server which does the sort of transformation and re-writing you are expecting and then point the proxy URL at that server.

You would want the important parts of your configuration to look something like this (assuming Intern 3 or later):

```
define([ 
    'intern',
    'my/server/main'
], function (intern, server) {
    return {
        proxyPort: 9000,
        proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9001/',
        setup: function() {
            if (intern.mode === 'runner') {
                server.start({ port: 9001 });
            }
        },
        teardown: function() {
            server.close();
        }
    };
});
```

You would need to create a proxy server that provides what functionality you need and passes through to the Intern proxy server when appropriate.  You would set the Intern proxy server to listen on a port (`proxyPort: 9000`) but you would instruct Intern to point the clients at the URL for your proxy server (`proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9001/'`) that is listening on a different port.  You would then use the `setup` and `teardown` properties to start and stop your server if the `intern.mode === 'runner'`.

For a practical example, take a look at [dojo/core](https://github.com/dojo/core/tree/master/tests), where the proxy server is located in `tests/services/echo.ts`.